# Filling missing data in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have been very hard lately on this. let me give you an example to start.

```
  Date      Name        Score      Percentage         Grade
3/23/2015    A            20           40                C
3/23/2015    B            15           30                D
3/23/2015    C            40           80                B
             D            45           
             E            35
```

Suppose percentage is double of score and Grade is based on percentage range. I update this table form a file which contains just 2 columns i.e Name,Score. What I do is copy the name and score to this file but I see that the other things don't get filled up automatically. can anyone recommend me on what can I do? . The way I can think is how can I drag or refresh after adding the new data?

Code:

```
// To Update.
Dim sht As Worksheet
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("NewRecords")
lastrow = sht.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

Range("B2:B" & lastrow).Copy ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main").Range("a65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 2)
Range("C2:C" & lastrow).Copy ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main").Range("a65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 1)
```

Comment: do you have formulas in the percentage and grade column?  if so then calculate the workbookt to update the formulas.

Comment: Consider changing your data to a table (Insert -> Table). Formulas get copied
down automatically and there are other benefits as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could fill formulas to the ranges just as:

```
Range("D2:D" & lastrow).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]*2"
Range("E2:E" & lastrow).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1] < 30, ""E"", IF(RC[-1] < 40, ""D"", IF(RC[-1] < 80, ""C"", IF(RC[-1] < 90, ""B"", ""A""))))"
```